# Using Python's multiprocessing in the middle of executing a pygame project

Tags: python, pygame, multiprocessing

This is my first time using the multiprocessing module and I'm just trying to figure out if what I'm going for is even vaugely feasable. I'm working on a little orbital simulation project for fun and have added a bunch of different optimisations to help it handle a large number of object, I figured this would be a good time to learn some multi threading. There's one particular function I want to speed up that just crunches some of the required math and I thought I'd be able to create a handful of processes to cut down the run time.

Original code looked like so:

```
for body in self.bodies:
    body.update_velocity(dt)
```

The multithread code I've just lifted from someone else looks like so:

```
procs = []
for body in self.bodies:
    proc = Process(target=update_velocity, args=(body, dt))
    procs.append(proc)proc.start()
for proc in procs:
    proc.join()
```

I did try doing this with Pool as well, but ended up having the same problem.
Sorry for the long wind up but the problem I'm having is that this ends up creating many copies of the pygame window and locks everything up. The function called only handles some vector math but clearly each process is duplicating all of the currently running code.

Some further research makes me think that to use multiprocessing I'll need to integrate it from the ground level and create each process from the get go. Is it possible at all to just spin up a handle full of processes in the middle of execution to parallelize one for loop or is this just not doable?

Thanks in advance, appologies if this is not clear

Comment: As far as I understand, multiprocessing initiates the processes by way of forking the base process, so that's why these extra pygame windows are being created. One way to get around this is for you to start up a service (which is easy to do with BaseManager), register the vector functions etc, and then initiate multiprocessing from the service process. There will of course be overheads as data going back and forth between processes is pickled and unpickled behind the scenes, but for large enough jobs you'll still get some gains out of it

Comment: To follow on from what @DmytroBugayev commented.  A `fork()` of a process is an *exact* copy.  So really you're starting your program multiple times.  To fix this you could write two scripts, one for the UI and another that sits waiting to get instructions.  Then use `subprocess.Popen()` to launch and communicate with it.

Comment: Maybe have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53643497/7675174) for an idea of the structure. In terms of multiprocessing, it'll probably be easier to create a separate file that is responsible for the number crunching and create a pool from that.